# NLog:: putting Line number in log file

Tags: nlog

I am beginner with NLog.

I want to save Line number along with my log entry.

```
1 <log content>
2 <log content>
3 <log content>
4 <log content>
.............
...........
n <log content>
```

where 1,2,3,.... n are line numbers in log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the numbering in the layout property of the target. There is a built in [layout renderer](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Layout_Renderers) for counting called [${counter}](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Counter_layout_renderer)

```
<target xsi:type="File" 
   name="file" 
   fileName="logfile.txt"
   layout="${counter} ${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"/>
```

Comment: However, the counter reset its value, so the same value could be repeated. For example if the web service is restarted, the counter resets to its default and repeats the old values.